# Gradle Idea plugin with dynamic source directories

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project build. I have written a plugin that the sub-projects use to configure tests, we have 3 flavours of testing and each sub-project will have unit tests but not necessarily the other 2. These plugins dynamically add to the sourceSets, and this can be overridden in the sub-project build.gradle.

The problem I am seeing is that these test paths are not added to the Idea modules when I generate them, presumably because my plugins are not evaluated before the Idea plugin identifies the source sets.

The top level build.gradle applies the Idea plugin in allprojects, and the test plugins are applied in the individual build.gradle files.

My questions are:

1. Is my assumption about evaluation order of the plugins correct?
2. How can I influence this evaluation order so the sourceSets are correctly configured before the Idea plugin is evaluated?

Many thanks

*** Edit ***

In the plugin I have

```
    private SourceSet configureSourceSet(File classesDir, Project project, testSourceDir) {
        def sourceSet = project.sourceSets.create(sourceSetName())
        sourceSet.output.classesDir = classesDir
        configureClasspathDependencies(project, sourceSet)
        def file = new File("$project.projectDir/$testSourceDir")
        if (project.plugins.hasPlugin('scala')) {
            sourceSet.scala.srcDirs += [file]
        } else {
            sourceSet.java.srcDirs += [file]
        }
        return sourceSet
    }
```

At the top of the modules build.gradle file I have

```
apply plugin: 'unitTest'
```

And in the top level gradle fle I have

```
allprojects {
    ext.buildDir = './build'

    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    idea.module {
        excludeDirs += file('install')
        excludeDirs += file('target')
        excludeDirs += file('tests_log')
        excludeDirs += file('.settings')
        downloadSources = false
    }
    eclipse.classpath {
        downloadSources = false
    }
}
```

*** Edit 2 ***

```
private void configureTestTask(Project project, File classesDir, SourceSet sourceSet) {
    def testTask = project.tasks.create(taskName(), Test)
    testTask.testClassesDir = classesDir
    testTask.classpath = sourceSet.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Comment: Please show all relevant code.

Comment: Looking at this a little further, it is not just about the stting of the sourceSets but also the task creation, I think. I have just gone through the projects and set the sourceSets within the modules build.gradle. Fo the extra directories injected by a different plugin into the main source tree these get correctly marked, however the test sources are not marked as test, is this because the task associated with the sourceSet, which is derived from Test, is not visible to the Idea plugin becaus ethe task itself is created in my plugin? Second edit shows the task creation code in the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption was incorrect. I downloaded the gradle plugin source and located the area that sets up the test source.

```
private def configureIdeaModuleForJava(Project project) {
    project.ideaModule {
        sourceDirs = project.sourceSets.main.allSource.sourceTrees.srcDirs.flatten()
        testSourceDirs = project.sourceSets.test.allSource.sourceTrees.srcDirs.flatten()
        outputDir = project.sourceSets.main.classesDir
        testOutputDir = project.sourceSets.test.classesDir
        def configurations = project.configurations
        scopes = [
                COMPILE: [plus: [configurations.compile], minus: []],
                RUNTIME: [plus: [configurations.runtime], minus: [configurations.compile]],
                TEST: [plus: [configurations.testRuntime], minus: [configurations.runtime]]
        ]
    }
}
```

the testSourceDirs only picks up source sets for test, whereas mine have names like testUtil. To overcome this my configureSourceSets becomes:

```
private SourceSet configureSourceSet(File classesDir, Project project, testSourceDir) {
    def sourceSet = project.sourceSets.create(sourceSetName())
    sourceSet.output.classesDir = classesDir
    configureClasspathDependencies(project, sourceSet)
    def file = new File("$project.projectDir/$testSourceDir")
    if (project.plugins.hasPlugin('scala')) {
        sourceSet.scala.srcDirs += [file]
    } else {
        sourceSet.java.srcDirs += [file]
    }
    sourceSet.resources.srcDirs += [file]
    sourceSet.resources.exclude("**/*.java")
    sourceSet.resources.exclude("**/*.scala")
    if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("idea")) {
        project.idea.module {
            testSourceDirs += sourceSet.allSource.srcDirs.flatten()
        }
    }
    return sourceSet
}
```